# avoid code duplication

Tags: java, code-duplication

consider the following code:

```
if (matcher1.find()) {
   String str = line.substring(matcher1.start()+7,matcher1.end()-1);
   /*+7 and -1 indicate the prefix and suffix of the matcher... */    
   method1(str);
}
if (matcher2.find()) {
   String str = line.substring(matcher2.start()+8,matcher2.end()-1);
   method2(str);
}
...
```

I have n matchers, all matchers are independent (if one is true, it says nothing about the others...), for each matcher which is true - I am invoking a different method on the content it matched.

**question:** I do not like the code duplication nor the "magic numbers" in here, but I'm wondering if there is better way to do it...? (maybe Visitor Pattern?) any suggestions?

Comment: If they are independent, you should be able to make on big regular expression and use http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.htmlto iterate over the substrings.

Comment: @Helper: 404 on your link, the "to" connected to the .html

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an abstract class, and add offset in subclass (with string processing too... depending of your requirement).

Then populate them in a list and process the list.

Here is a sample absract processor:

```
public abstract class AbsractProcessor {

    public void find(Pattern pattern, String line) {
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(line);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            process(line.substring(matcher.start() + getStartOffset(), matcher.end() - getEndOffset()));
        }
    }

    protected abstract int getStartOffset();

    protected abstract int getEndOffset();

    protected abstract void process(String str);

}
```

Comment: It seems elegant, I am still thinking if it is not a bit too much for my case (a bit like catching a butterfly with a cannon) +1 anyway, for the elegance.

Comment: It's seems too much because Java is too much verbose, would be more elegant with a language with functional flavour like Scala or Python.

Comment: But one of my golden rule is: NEVER EVER NEVER duplicate any code... or you gonna correct the same bug multiple time (or forgot to...). That's the power of abstraction... and IMHO that's what make you a good programmer. BTW, accept the answer if it's ok for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Simple mark the part of the regex that you want to pass to the method with a capturing group.

For example if your regex is `foo.*bar` and you are not interested in `foo` or `bar`, make the regex `foo(.*)bar`. Then always grab the group 1 from the `Matcher`.

Your code would then look like this:

```
method1(matcher1.group(1));
method2(matcher2.group(2));
...
```

One further step would be to replace your methods with classes implementing an like this:

```
public interface MatchingMethod {
  String getRegex();
  void apply(String result);
}
```

Then you can easily automate the task:

```
for (MatchingMethod mm : getAllMatchingMethods()) {
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile(mm.getRegex());
  Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
  while (m.find()) {
    mm.apply(m.group(1));
}
```

Note that if performance is important, then pre-compiling the `Pattern` can improve runtime if you apply this to many inputs.

Comment: +1 for using capturing groups, which cleans this up quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it a little bit shorter, but I the question is, is this really worth the effort:

```
private String getStringFromMatcher(Matcher matcher, int magicNumber) {
   return line.subString(matcher.start() + magicNumber, matcher.end() - 1 )
}

if (matcher1.find()) {
method1(getStringFromMatcher(matcher1, 7);
}

if (matcher2.find()) {
method2.(getStringFromMatcher(mather2, 8);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use Cochard's solution combined with a factory (switch statement) with all the methodX methods. so you can call it like this:

```
Factory.CallMethodX(myEnum.MethodX, str)
```

you can assign the myEnum.MethodX in the population step of Cochard's solution